# Simple rock, paper, scissors game [Python]

Tags: python, if-statement, random, python-2.x

I'm trying to write a simple RPS game but I'm having trouble getting the program to display the result of the game. Mind you, I'm a total beginner in programming and I've written all this from what I've learned previously so it probably isn't the most efficent way to write a game like this.

```
import random
rps = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
rps2 = (random.choice(rps))

print 'Welcome to RPS'
print 'Press 1 to pick Rock'
print 'Press 2 to pick Paper'
print 'Press 3 to pick Scissors'
print 'Press 4 to quit.'


while True:
    game = int(raw_input('What do you pick? '))
    if game == 1:
        print 'You picked rock.'
        print 'The computer picked...' + (random.choice(rps))
        if rps2 == [0]:
            print 'It\'s a tie!'
        elif rps2 == [1]:
            print 'You lose!'
        elif rps2 == [2]:
            print 'You win!'
    elif game == 2:
        print 'You picked paper.'
        print 'The computer picked...' + (random.choice(rps))
        if rps2 == [0]:
            print 'You win!'
        elif rps2 == [1]:
            print 'It\'s a tie!'
        elif rps2 == [2]:
            print 'You lose!'
    elif game == 3:
        print 'You picked scissors.'
        print 'The computer picked...' + (random.choice(rps))
    if rps2 == [0]:
        print 'You lose!'
    elif rps2 == [1]:
        print 'You win!'
    elif rps2 == [2]:
        print 'It\'s a tie!'
    elif game == 4:
        print 'Thank you for playing!'
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: I'm adding the python tag. If you even put python in the title, why not use the tag?

Comment: Oh, I simply forgot about it :)

Comment: Check your indentation in the final block; that may be a problem. There are some other obvious issues too. First, `rps2` is initiated once, at the start of the program, then you display other randomly chosen items without actually updating the `rps2` variable. Second, `if rps2 == [0]` is not valid. Try `if rps2 is rps[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't make much sense; the line

```
    print 'The computer picked...' + (random.choice(rps))
```

picks a random element from `rps`, so either `'rock'`, `paper` or `scissors`. But you just print that element, and don't save it.

Then you go and compare the element that was randomly chosen before the first time you asked your user:

```
    if rps2 == [0]:
```

That doesn't make sense. You're comparing a string (one element of `rps`) with a list with 0 as the only element.

What you probably wanted to do was something like

```
while True:
    game = int(raw_input('What do you pick? '))
    if game == 1:
        print 'You picked rock.'
        computerpick = random.choice(rps)
        print 'The computer picked...' + computerpick
        if computerpick == 'rock':
            print 'It\'s a tie!'
        elif computerpick == 'paper':
            print 'You lose!'
        elif rps2 == 'scissors':
            print 'You win!'
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, in the comparison:

```
    if rps2 == [0]:
        print 'It\'s a tie!'
    elif rps2 == [1]:
        print 'You lose!'
    elif rps2 == [2]:
        print 'You win!'
```

You should write it

```
    if rps2 == rps[0]:
        print 'It\'s a tie!'
    elif rps2 == rps[1]:
        print 'You lose!'
    elif rps2 == rps[2]:
        print 'You win!'
```

Since you want to access the list of rps.

You also have wrong indentation there. I modified it as this:

```
import random
rps = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
rps2 = (random.choice(rps))

print 'Welcome to RPS'
print 'Press 1 to pick Rock'
print 'Press 2 to pick Paper'
print 'Press 3 to pick Scissors'
print 'Press 4 to quit.'


while True:
    game = int(raw_input('What do you pick? '))
    if game == 1:
        print 'You picked rock.'
        print 'The computer picked...' + (random.choice(rps))
        if rps2 == rps[0]:
            print 'It\'s a tie!'
        elif rps2 == rps[1]:
            print 'You lose!'
        elif rps2 == rps[2]:
            print 'You win!'
    elif game == 2:
        print 'You picked paper.'
        print 'The computer picked...' + (random.choice(rps))
        if rps2 == rps[0]:
            print 'You win!'
        elif rps2 == rps[1]:
            print 'It\'s a tie!'
        elif rps2 == rps[2]:
            print 'You lose!'
    elif game == 3:
        print 'You picked scissors.'
        print 'The computer picked...' + (random.choice(rps))
        if rps2 == rps[0]:
            print 'You lose!'
        elif rps2 == rps[1]:
            print 'You win!'
        elif rps2 == rps[2]:
            print 'It\'s a tie!'
    elif game == 4:
        print 'Thank you for playing!'
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Tested.